# Trouble parsing JSON

Tags: json, swift

I am having trouble parsing some JSON in Swift. I am having trouble getting the `errors` variable it returns nil. I think it should be a dictionary?
Below is the JSON that is returned from my API as printed in the console.

```
{
    error = "{\"name\":[\"The name has already been taken.\"],\"email\":[\"The email has already been taken.\"]}";
    success = 0;
}
```

And here is the Swift code.

```
do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

    if let parseJSON = json {
        print(parseJSON)
        let success = parseJSON["success"] as? Int

        if(success == 1) {
            let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Registration successful", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){
                (action) in
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

            myAlert.addAction(okAction);
            self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            let errors = parseJSON["error"] as? NSDictionary
            if(errors != nil){
                print("NOT NIL")
                // self.displayAlertMessage()
            }
        }
    }
} catch{
    print(error)
}
```

**EDIT**
Here is the JSON thats is printed using David's code below.
This is the parseJSON printed to the console.

```
["error": {"name":["The name has already been taken."],"email":["The email has already been taken."]}, "success": 0]
```

Here is my full method with Davids updated code.

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (theData: Data?, response: URLResponse?, theError: Error?) in

    DispatchQueue.main.async
        {

            //spinningActivity!.hide(true)

            if theError != nil {
                self.displayAlertMessage(theError!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            do {
                guard let parseJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: theData!) as? [String:Any] else {return}
                //print(parseJSON)
                let success = parseJSON["success"] as? Int
                if(success == 1) {
                    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Registration successful", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);

                    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){
                        (action) in
                        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }

                    myAlert.addAction(okAction);
                    self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                } else {
                    guard let errors = parseJSON["success"] as? Int else {return}
                    print(errors)
                }
            } catch{
                print(error)
            }



    }

}

task.resume()
```

Comment: What is the incoming JSON (not the decode of it; the actual JSON you receive; `String(data: data, using:.utf8)`)? And what, exactly, do you want the output to be? (What type should it be, and exactly what contents for this incoming JSON)?

Comment: Here is what is being printed. I used the following method as "using" was not recognized.  let theString = String(data: theData!, encoding:.utf8)print (theString!) And here is the string as printed to console. {"success":false,"error":"{\"name\":[\"The name has already been taken.\"],\"email\":[\"The email has already been taken.\"]}"}

Comment: I figured it out using your suggestion. It seems I was double encoding the JSON. If you add your suggestion as an answer somehow I will mark as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code that might be not causing the issue directly, but are bad practices. Don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift, use `[String:Any]` when decoding JSON responses and don't use `.mutableContainers` as it has no effect in `Swift`, the mutability is determined by the `let` or `var` keyword when declaring the variable.

Moreover, don't include console print as the JSON response, include the actual JSON response in your question, as Swift's `print` statement doesn't produce a valid JSON.

```
let apiErrorResponse = """
{
    "error": {
        "name": "The name has already been taken.",
        "email": ["The email has already been taken."]
    },
    "success": 0
}
"""
func handleApiErrorResponse(){
    do {
        guard let parseJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: apiErrorResponse.data(using: .utf8)!) as? [String:Any] else {return}
        let success = parseJSON["success"] as? Int
        if(success == 1) {
            let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Registration successful", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){
                (action) in
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

            myAlert.addAction(okAction);
            self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            guard let errors = parseJSON["error"] as? [String:Any] else {return}
            print(errors)
        }
    } catch{
        print(error)
    }
}

handleApiErrorResponse()
```

Output:

> "["name": The name has already been taken., "email": <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x608000019f80>(\nThe email has already been taken.\n)\n]\n"

Comment: The JSON was more readable your way. But I am still having trouble parsing the error. I updated my answer to show new JSON that is printed.

Comment: And what is the issue now? The JSON is parsed and printed, so I don't see what's wrong. In your question you said the `error` variable was `nil`, which is clearly not the case using my code.

Comment: I have no idea. I am using your exact code. Only I am not getting the errors, I showed the parseJSON and it seems valid. But alas I am not getting the errors. If i use guard let errors = parseJSON["success"] as? Int else {return}
print(errors) i am getting 0 in the console

Comment: I am going to update my answer with the full code from that method. This is coming from an NSURLRequest

Comment: What you are saying in comments and showin in your question is completely contradictive. After your edit you state that using my code you get the correct output and you show the correct output and then you say it's not working. Moreover, why would you do `let errors = parseJSON["success"] as? Int `? That's not what my code does and `errors` and `success` are completely different.  Moreover, this is Swift, why are you using old Foundation data types? Use `URLRequest` instead of `NSURLRequest`.

Comment: The correct output is the parseJSON I meant it seems to be valid data coming from the server. I meant I was using URLRequest. The reason I stated I did   let errors = parseJSON["success"] as? Int was to show that the JSON was able to be read correctly. Sorry for being so confusing.

Comment: After your new edit, you state blatantly incorrect things again. The code in your question is not the same as the code in my answer. Just use the exact same code for parsing as shown in my answer and it will work perfectly. Moreover, don't dispatch everything to the main queue, that's bad practice, only dispatch the code that updates the UI. Only 2 lines of code need to be dispatched to the main queue, namely: `DispatchQueue.main.async{self.displayAlertMessage(theError!.localizedDescription)}` then `DispatchQueue.main.async{self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160874/discussion-between-james-and-david-pasztor).

Comment: I changed back to your exact code and it is not working. Thanks for the tips about the dispatching.